# Any suggestion to generate newlist.append(q) list faster than current method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

Hi I am trying to generate a list of elements q by using below mentioned code.

```
newlist=[]
coords=pn['point.coords'][z>=0.001950]
points=range(27000)
for q in points:
    if pn['point.coords'][q] in coords: 
        newlist.append(q)
```

Here `pn['point.coords']` is a list of `x ,y ,z` coordinates of points and I want to make a new list of those points in which `z>= 0.001950`. Total limit of `x,y,z` is from `0 to 0.002`. Code is running slow. Is there any faster way to get this new list?

Comment: Have you tried numpy.where function?

Comment: Many linear-time searches in coords. Sort it and use binary-search (if big enough). Currently it looks like O(n_points * n_coords) complexity.

Comment: can't you create a `set` out of `coords` ? (it's not numpy-compliant but if it works...)

Comment: @VinceW. How can I use numpy.where for this problem. I am new to this function? (sascha) I didn't get what do you mean by many linear times searches. How can I do binary search?

Comment: Look up what ```in``` is doing. Grab a data-structures course and search for python + binary-search or numpy + binary-search.

Comment: One thing is certain; `numpy` is the way to do this. Vanilla Python will be much slower with `filter` implementations.

Comment: Nope... it's about 1d-lookups and it does not matter if python's or numpy's bin-search is used. This is a pretty basic data-structures problem including decisions on linear-search vs. balanced-search-trees vs. hash-based sets (and this decision depends on details not given).

Comment: @sascha coords is an array like this `array([[  1.59207770e-04,   1.32789505e-03,   5.98304165e-04],
       [  6.20949329e-05,   1.62185466e-03,   1.72185906e-04],
       [  1.12003158e-04,   1.21663881e-03,   1.05672481e-03],
       ..., 
       [  1.74749403e-04,   1.69110522e-03,   1.69335461e-03],
       [  8.27783343e-05,   2.70784593e-04,   1.57954356e-03],
       [  2.18524596e-04,   1.22997816e-03,   1.43195636e-03]])` where first, second and third elements are `x,y,z` respectively.

Comment: In this case (coords is tiny) a lot changes. But at the same time i'm not even sure your code maps to your task anymore (depends on specifics not given). Create some complete reproducible example, including input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). The numpy way is

```
coords = pn['point.coords']
z = coords[:,2]
q, = np.where(z>0.001950)
high_points=coords[q]
```

The other point is that this is a linear time  program.
Yours is quadratic, because `p in coords` have a hidden complexity.
For little value of `zmax`, the execution time will quickly augment.

Comment: speed comparion?

Comment: @B.M.Superb answer. The code was taking 4sec previously now it is taking 0.29 sec. Thank you very much.